# What does やっぱり mean in [そこまでなんだって、思っちゃうもん……やっぱり]

Tags: meaning, spoken-language, word-order

> 「もうみーくん、またそういうこと言って」
>
> 「駄目ですか？」
>
> 「ううん、それも嬉しい、ドキドキする」
>
> 「そこまでなんだって、思っちゃうもん……**やっぱり**」

I'm a bit confused as to what this やっぱり is doing in the sentence above.

Comment: Nice try. How about the other 4 sentences ?

Comment: That's a lot of context for a single word. I think it's adding a hesitant emphasis, with a lot more positivity than 多分, though as a beginner myself, that opinion has little weight. It would be helpful to see where this 少女 banter is coming from. Audio? Video? Image? A link would help people help you. :)

Answer (score 6):

やっぱり has several meanings, such as:

> - **やっぱり**、思った通りだ。 -- It is so, *just as I thought/expected/suspected*. -> That's exactly what I thought. / I knew it.
> - **やっぱり**、こっちにします。 -- *On second thought*, / *I changed my mind*, I'll pick this one.
> - それでも / なんだかんだ言っても、**やっぱり**嬉しいです。 -- But I'm happy, *nonetheless / all the same / after all*.

Here in your sentence, I think it's used as the 3rd meaning, "nonetheless, after all, all the same".

> そこまでなんだって思っちゃうもん…やっぱり。
>   Because it makes me realize you think of me so much... after all / nonetheless.

Comment: 実際は On second thought じゃなくて On third thought な気がします。やっぱり First thought に戻るって時に使うことが多いです。Still the first/original  thought/choice is convincing って思った時に使いませんか？

Comment: @Wataru'Watson'Subridge 両方の場合があると思います。「当初は行きたくなかったものを、行こうって誘われて行くことにしたけど、やっぱりいやだわ、やめるわ～」っていうときは 「first thought に戻る」って感じですけど、「コーヒーください。あっ！待って、やっぱり紅茶にします。」ってときには second thought でしょう？両方書いたほうがいいですかね・・(on third thought って、どんな感じですか。「もう一回考え直して」みたいな感じでしょうか。)

Answer (score -1):

やっぱり is frequently used when someone is uncertain about what to do or how to feel about something. For example:

> イギリスに行こうかな。。。いや、やっぱり日本に行く！
>
> Maybe I should go to England. No, actually I'll go to Japan!

Regarding your dialog, without the full context and knowing what they are talking about, it is hard to say for certain, but here I get the feeling that the person saying "やっぱり" was sort of indecisive about something and now has decided a bit more firmly. Or possibly they just thought about something for a second or two before deciding their stance on it. I think colloquial use of "actually" contains some of this feeling.