# Meaning and usage of やっぱり (矢っ張り)

Tags: meaning, usage, adverbs

I got "As expected" is the meaning of this word from Google Translate (is it correct?) and I guess this word is used in casual conversation (what is the polite version?).

I would like to know it's meaning and usage(both is casual and formal conversation)

Comment: Does this help? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/420/9831

Comment: @Shoko It did not help. I am focusing on meaning and usage of やっぱり only with example ( FYI, I am beginner)

Comment: Then this will be of some help, maybe? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34166/9831

Comment: @Shoko Yes it helped but I would like you to answer my question with at least one example **(especially when the word used at the beginning of a sentence)**

Comment: @Shoko (2nd link >> answer of @Locksleyu ) `イギリスに行こうかな。。。いや、やっぱり日本に行く！
Maybe I should go to England. No, actually I'll go to Japan!`.  And I got other meaning i.e. likewise, nonetheless(your answer of 2nd link). So still confused little bit

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question and clarify what you're still unsure about after looking at the other questions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

やっぱり is a colloquial/casual version of やはり.
やっぱり/やはり has several meanings/usages. For example...

"as expected; as (one) would expect"

> - **やはり**それは本当だった。It was true, *just as I thought/expected/imagined*.
> - 「犯人は彼だった。」「**やっぱり**ね。」"He was the criminal." "*Just as I thought/suspected*. ⇒ That's what I thought. / I knew it."
> - **やっぱり**言ったとおりだろう。That's exactly what I said. / Didn't I tell you so?
> - 「**やっぱり**（≂さすがは）イナバ、100人乗っても大丈夫。」 100 people can stand on Inaba's storage shed, *just as one would expect*.

"change one's mind / on second thought"

> - コーヒーください。いや、**やっぱり**紅茶にします。I'll have a coffee... No, *I changed my mind / on second thought*, make it a tea.

"all the same; nonetheless; after all"

> - 冬は**やっぱり**スキーに限る。 Winter is the best season for skiing, *after all*.
> - 小さいけど、**やっぱり**この町が好きです。This town is small, but I like it *nonetheless / all the same*.
> - チョコレートは**やっぱり**明治。Meiji's chocolate is the best.

("as expected to be the same as before" ⇒) "still"

> - 今も**やはり**XXにお勤めですか。Do you *still* work for XX company?
> - 彼女は今も**やっぱり**きれいだ。She's *as* beautiful *as ever*.
> - **やっぱり**わかりません。I *still* don't understand.

("as expected to be the same as something/someone else" ⇒) "too; likewise"

> - **やはり**ここも売り切れか。It's sold out here, *too*.
> - 弟さんも**やっぱり**X大出身？ Did your brother graduate from X University, *like* you?

Comment: Good answer. We don't use the kanji for this, either, maybe this is worth mentioning for OP's sake. It's pretty odd.

Comment: @virgil9306 ありがとうございます☺  Right, we rarely use the kanji 矢張り or 矢っ張り. It's almost always written in Hiragana (at least in modern Japanese).

Comment: やはり in turn is cognate with やわら.  The kanji are purely ateji.