# やっぱり to mean “after all” + other uses?

Tags: word-usage

i just saw やっぱり used to mean “after all” and another place it was translated as “definitely”. later on was the sentence 「やっぱりこういう風になると」and the translation was “But, when you became like this”

basically, what are some different uses of やっぱり besides “just as i thought” or “i knew it”?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43299/9831

Comment: this is absolutely perfect, どうもありがとう！！！